# Using AMPScript to find min value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I'm trying to the minimum value of 3 variables I set in ampScript.

```
%%[ var @hotel_1_price, @hotel_2_price, @hotel_3_price, @lowestPrice

SET @hotel_1_price = 139
SET @hotel_2_price = 124
SET @hotel_3_price = 72

if (@hotel_1_price < @hotel_2_price and @hotel_1_price < @hotel_3_price) then
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_1_price
elseif (@ hotel_2_price < @hotel_3_price and @hotel_2_price < @hotel_1_price) then
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_2_price
else 
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_3_price
endif

outputline(concat("Starting at ","$",@lowestPrice,": Hotels near ",@venue_name))
]%%
```

Can't seem to figure this out, I'm always getting 124 as the minimum value.

Comment: You can't use `Math.Min();`  That's client-side JavaScript, not server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep it all server-side, you'd have to do something like this:

```
%%[

var @value_1, @value_2, @value_3
set @value_1 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 1")
set @value_2 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 2")
set @value_3 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 3")

/* for testing */
set @value_1 = "2"
set @value_2 = "3"
set @value_3 = "1"

outputline(concat("<br>value_1: ",@value_1))
outputline(concat("<br>value_2: ",@value_2))
outputline(concat("<br>value_3: ",@value_3))


]%%

<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var v1 = Variable.GetValue("@value_1");
var v2 = Variable.GetValue("@value_2");
var v3 = Variable.GetValue("@value_3");
Write("<br>v1: "+ v1);
Write("<br>v2: "+ v2);
Write("<br>v3: "+ v3);

var lowestValue = 0;

if (v1 < v2 && v1 < v3) {
    lowestValue = v1;
} else if (v2 < v3 && v2 < v1) {
    lowestValue = v2;
} else {
    lowestValue = v3;
}
Write("<br>lowestValue: "+ lowestValue);

</script>
```

**Output**

```
value_1: 2 
value_2: 3 
value_3: 1 
v1: 2
v2: 3
v3: 1
lowestValue: 1
```

**Reference**

- [**AttributeValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/)
- [**Variable.GetValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/variable_utility_functions/getvalue/)

**Update (All AMPScript)**

```
%%[

var @hotel_price_1, @hotel_price_2, @hotel_price_3, @lowestPrice
set @hotel_price_1 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 1")
set @hotel_price_2 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 2")
set @hotel_price_3 = AttributeValue("Lookup field 3")

/* for testing */
set @hotel_price_1 = add("139",0)
set @hotel_price_2 = add("124",0)
set @hotel_price_3 = add("72",0)

outputline(concat("<br>hotel_price_1: ",@hotel_price_1))
outputline(concat("<br>hotel_price_2: ",@hotel_price_2))
outputline(concat("<br>hotel_price_3: ",@hotel_price_3))

set @lowestPrice = 0

if (@hotel_price_1 < @hotel_price_2 and @hotel_price_1 < @hotel_price_3) then
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_price_1
elseif (@hotel_price_2 < @hotel_price_3 and @hotel_price_2 < @hotel_price_1) then
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_price_2
else 
    set @lowestPrice = @hotel_price_3
endif

outputline(concat("<br>Starting at ","$",@lowestPrice,": Hotels near ",@venue_name))

]%%
```

**Output**

```
hotel_price_1: 139 
hotel_price_2: 124 
hotel_price_3: 72 
Starting at $72: Hotels near
```

Comment: Thank you!! If I wanted to do this all with Ampscript, how would I do it? I only wanted to use SSJS because I couldn't get it to work with ampscript.

Comment: You can do the same if-then with the AMPScript to find the lowest of the three values.  Updated my answer above.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a weird quirk if I am using a decimal data type? For some reason, I am not getting the correct minimum value with this logic. It makes total sense to me but I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: Use the Add() function to convert the vars to numbers. Just add zero.

Comment: Updated my example above.  Please don't add answers to clarify your questions.